# Summarize table by rows, based on specific tresholds by column

Tags: excel

I am trying to summarize a "flagged" table by rows, based on specific tresholds by column. This is an example:

[image: Example with final result = 2]

The final result here is 2 and should be calculated in a **single cell** only, by not using any additional columns.

My table has thousands of rows, so that I am trying to keep this formula flexible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an array formula. Basically the formula creates a total of how many items in each row meet the criteria, then raises it to 0 to make them all either 1 or error, changes errors to 0, and then sums them. If you don't understand how it works, I would suggest highlighting part of the formula and hitting f9 to see just how that portion works.

Remember to enter with control + shift + enter

`=SUM(IFERROR((--($B$4:B6>$B$1)+--($C$4:C6>$C$1)+--(D4:$D$6>$D$1))^0,0))`

[image]